# Visual Studio 2019 won't compile any C# project after Visual Studio 2017 uninstall

Tags: visual-studio

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017, then installed Visual Studio 2019.

Visual Studio 2019 doesn't compile any C# project, even if I make a completely new one, with this error:

```
The specified task executable location "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe" is invalid.
```

I can't find where this path is stored. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you restart after installing?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras Yes, multiple times (I also repaired 2019 installation and restart again)

Comment: For now I just found the workaround to create a directory junction with this command, but I would like to find a cleaner solution: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild>mklink /J 15.0 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\"

Comment: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild` path related to VS 2017, it seems that haven't removed it properly

Comment: Please try to find visual studio installer->click more-> repair your visual studio.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I already tried but it didn't solve the problem.